# When inserting with tableadapter in one form, how to refresh data in another?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 Express, Windows Forms.

Have made myself my first little application which used a local database (a journal app).
First form (which load when app starts) shows every entry that has been made.
A "Add button" show up a new form, from where I can add a new entry.

Now, everything works this far.

But when I close the add form, after adding a new entry, the new entry isn't displayed in the first form. I have to close the program and start it up again the see the new entry.

How can I refresh the data in the first form, when the add form closes?

Best regards from Denmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you must open your second form as dialog like `new FormAdd().ShowDialog(this);`

this will stop the code until **FormAdd** close, then you can reload the data as you load in form firs load.

your code will be like this

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new FormAdd().ShowDialog();
    LoadData();
}
private void LoadData()
{ 
   //load your data
}
```

by the way you can use **DialogResult** for unnecessary prevent refreshs is user does not insert a record to db. in **FormAdd** code set DialogResult value and in main form use like this

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (new FormAdd().ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        LoadData();
}
```

Comment: Of course ;) Still new to StackOverflow :) Should be marked now. Best regards, and once again thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old post, but in looking for an answer on this site to the same situation, I also discovered another method which, may work as well.

I also have Visual Studio 2010 Express, Windows Forms. I invoke a separate form via a MenuStrip button click. Using this 2nd form, I add various hours-of-the-day to a dataGridView on my main form, i.e., 9:00AM, 9:30AM etc.

I found that after adding a new time, when I clicked a combobox dropdown button on my dataGridView that, the new entry was not there. Like the original poster, I would have to close and reopen my main form.

In my Form_Load event, VS had added a TableAdapter entry, which loads data into the table, i.e.

> this.TimesTableAdapter.Fill(this.AssignmentsDataSet.Times);

However, by copying this line into the form's Form__Activated event, when I click on the dataGridView's dropdown list, the newly created entry now appears. 
Hopefully, this proves useful to any who run into the same issue.